# Getting "TypeError: type of out argument not recognized: <class 'str'>" when using class function with Pandera decorator

Tags: python, pandas, pandera

I am trying to get to use decorators from Python package "Pandera" and I am having trouble to get them work with classes.

First I create schemas for Pandera:

```
from pandera import Column, Check
import yaml
in_ = pa.DataFrameSchema(
    {
        "Name": Column(object, nullable=True),
        "Height": Column(object, nullable=True),
    })

with open("./in_.yml", "w") as file:
    yaml.dump(in_, file)

out_ = pa.DataFrameSchema(
    {
        "Name": Column(object, nullable=True),
        "Height": Column(object, nullable=True),
    })
with open("./out_.yml", "w") as file:
    yaml.dump(out_, file)
```

Next I create `test.py` file with class:

```
from pandera import check_io
import pandas as pd

class TransformClass():

    with open("./in_.yml", "r") as file:
        in_ = file.read()
    with open("./out_.yml", "r") as file:
        out_ = file.read()

    @staticmethod
    @check_io(df=in_, out=out_)
    def func(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return df
```

Finally I importing this class:

```
from test import TransformClass
data = {'Name': [np.nan, 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],
        'Height': [5.1, 6.2, 5.1, 5.2],
        'Qualification': ['Msc', 'MA', 'Msc', 'Msc']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
TransformClass.func(df)
```

I am getting:

```
File C:\Anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\pandera\decorators.py:464, in check_io.<locals>._wrapper(fn, instance, args, kwargs)
    462     out_schemas = []
    463 else:
--> 464     raise TypeError(
    465         f"type of out argument not recognized: {type(out)}"
    466     )
    468 wrapped_fn = fn
    469 for input_getter, input_schema in inputs.items():
    470     # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

TypeError: type of out argument not recognized: <class 'str'>
```

Any help would much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `check_io` decorator expects arguments of type `pandera.DataFrameSchema`. However, it is being passed `_out` which is type `str` since it is the output of `file.read()`.

The [Pandera docs](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/decorators.html?highlight=check_io#check-io) explain which types the `check_io` decorator is expecting.

A solution would be to pass the output of the `file.read()` line to the Pandera constructor, possibly with some transformation:

```
out_ = yaml.safe_load(file.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @grbeazley here is the full solution:

```
from pandera import Column, Check
import yaml

in_ = pa.DataFrameSchema(
    {
        "Name": Column(object, nullable=True),
        "Height": Column(object, nullable=True),
    })
with open("in_.yml", "w") as file:
    yaml.dump(in_.to_yaml(), file)

with open("./in_.yml", "r") as file:
    in_ = yaml.safe_load(file.read())

_ = pa.DataFrameSchema.from_yaml(in_)
```